# When electrons move regardless of what the voltage is, is the strength of the magnetic field a constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, electric-current, voltage

When electrons move regardless of the what the voltage is, is the strength of the magnetic field a constant?

My understanding of the ammeter is the magnetic field of the moving electron effectively moves the needle and this tells us the amps. But, this would mean regardless of the voltage all electrons must create the same magnetic field strength?

How do you prove experimentally this is true? Have there been experiments to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the strength of the magnetic field produced by a (constant) electrical current only depends on the current. It does not depend on the electrostatic voltage which put those charges into motion in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I am not a physicist, but I find these materials interesting to learn. How do you increase the current without increasing the voltage? If you connect two batteries in parallel would that work?

Comment: Well there are a lot of ways, depending on what materials  & equipment you are using. If you connect multiple wires to the same battery, each wire will have the same amount of current as before, so you will have multiplied your current. The only possible issue is now the battery will drain much faster.

Another way to increase current would be to use a wire which has lower electrical resistance.